# Mach-O Linker (Id) Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have just added the Google Tools for Mac OAuth classes to a project and get the following linker error[image]

Any ideas what I need to do? It is an iPad app if that makes any difference.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: It looks like you have redefined _kGTMOAuth2ServiceProviderGoogle in your RootViewController.

Comment: I haven't redefined it anywhere as far as I am aware, and where would I go to un-redefine it?

Comment: Did you #include or #import "GTMOAuth2Authentication.h", hint it should be import. If this is the case I will add an answer.

Comment: You were close, just noticed I had used autocomplete on the #import statements and hit the .m files and not the .h header files. The Mach-O error messages weren't very helpful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a result of redefining a symbol in your RootViewController. There are few possible reasons for this.

1. In RootViewController you explicitly defined kGTMOAuth2ServiceProviderGoogle
2. You used [#include instead of #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c)
3. You #import or #include the implementation file (.m)