# Duplicate protocol definition warning

Tags: objective-c, llvm, llvm-clang

First, I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138689/warning-duplicate-protocol-definition-of-is-ignored) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001293/duplicate-protocol-definition-warning-but-i-need-multiples-of-this-protocol), but my problem is not addressed there.

I have a protocol `ProtocolA` defined in its own header file. Then I have two classes `ClassA` and `ClassB` which both conform to this protocol so the protocol-header is imported in their header files.

Now it gets a bit complicated. `ClassA` is used (and thus imported) in a third `ClassC`. This class conforms to a second protocol `ProtocolB`. This protocol also has its own header file where it uses and imports `ClassB`. So my `ClassC` imports (either directly or indirectly) both `ClassA` and `ClassB` (which both import `ProtocolA`). This gives me the following warning regarding `ProtocolA`:

```
warning: duplicate protocol definition of '…' is ignored
```

Why is this happening? It was my understanding that the `#import` macro was invented exactly for avoiding this kind of problems which we had with `#include`. How can I solve the issue without using an include guard? I can't really remove any of the imports.

**EDIT:** here is the code to illustrate the situation:

`ProtocolA.h`

```
@protocol ProtocolA <NSObject>
- (void)someMethod;
@end
```

`ClassA.h`

```
#import "ProtocolA.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject <ProtocolA>
...
@end
```

`ClassB.h`

```
#import "ProtocolA.h"

@interface ClassB : NSObject <ProtocolA>
typedef enum Type {
    TypeB1,
    TypeB2
} TypeB;
...
@end
```

`ProtocolB.h`

```
#import "ClassB.h"

@protocol ProtocolB <NSObject>
- (TypeB)someMethod;
@end
```

`ClassC.h`

```
#import "ProtocolB.h"

@interface ClassC : NSObject <ProtocolB>
...
@end
```

`ClassC.m`

```
#import "ClassC.h"
#import "ClassA.h" // the warning appears here

@implementation ClassC
...
@end
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code; your description is hard to follow.

Comment: I have added example code. Although I admit, it can still be hard to follow.

Comment: Using forward declarations is the answer.  If you only ever use `ClassA *` within `ClassB.h` then use `@class ClassA;` at the start of the file.  Same for protocols.

Answer (score 0):

do not Import `ClassB` in `ProtocolB` header, just use `@class ClassB;` in it and remove `#import "ClassB"`

Comment: There is no indication the OP is importing the class header from the protocol header, unless I missed it...

Comment: read again , "This class conforms to a second protocol ProtocolB. This protocol also has its own header file where it uses and imports ClassB."

Comment: `ClassB` header is indeed imported in `ProtocolB`. This is done because one of the methods of `ProtocolB` return an enum type which is defined in the header of `ClassB`. So `@class ClassB;` won't really work, unless I can somehow forward declare an enum.

Comment: Move your struct declaration in its own file

Comment: Yeah using `@class SomeClass;` is often required when declaring a protocol.

Comment: ogres, moving the enum to its own file was the solution, thanks! If you edit your answer I will accept it.

Comment: or just front declare the protocol

Comment: Daij-Djan, you cannot forward declare a protocol when conforming to it as the class will not know its methods etc. It only works when your are solely using it as a type.