# Scope of a typedef in a header file

Tags: objective-c, typedef

If I place a `typedef enum{kOne,kTwo}whatever;` in a `.h` above the `@interface`, I know I can use it by method implementations in the `.m`. That is, I can use `kOne` and `kTwo` freely.

Now, I know I can make an `@property` of `whatever` thereby exposing the chosen kValue of `whatever` to other classes, if desired.

But what if I want to expose the enum guts of `whatever`, so I can access `kOne` and `kTwo` from other classes? That is, I want to know how many are included in `whatever` and access those constants too. For example, I want another class to know that `kOne` is 0, `kTwo` is 1, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `#import` the appropriate header file, just as you need to in order to use the class for which it is defined.

You do *not* need the include guards in @dwerner's answer because you should *not* use `#include` for Objective-C headers. Use `#import` instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can put the typedef in it's own header, and surround with

```
#ifndef __MY_TYPEDEF__
typedef enum{kOne,kTwo}whatever;
#endif
```

and just `#include` this where needed.