# what's the difference between import and include in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between #import and #include in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c)

It seems both can work when I use import or include in Objective-C, what's the difference between those two?

Comment: this question has already been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

..#include and #import request that the preprocessor read a file and add it to its output.
The difference between #include and #import is that

- #include  allow you to include the same file many times.
- #import ensures that the preprocessor only includes a file once.

C programmers tend to use #include. 
Objective-C programmers tend to user #import.

Compiling a file in Objective-C is done in two passes. First, the preprocessor runs through the file. The output from the preprocessor goes into the real compiler. 
Preprocessor directives start with #. The three most popular are

-#include

-#import

-#define