# what is the difference between #import(include) and : (inherit) functionally

Tags: objective-c

I don't seem to understand what the difference between **#import** (then declaring Pointer to that class) and **inheritance** as i can both have **reference** to that super class or the class included..

And, in addition to this topic, view **mustn't know** about view controller for loose coupling reason. does this mean that view shouldn't **#include** any controller and having reference to that controller??

I think I'm missing some basic concept that makes me so confused here ..
Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: This is an Objective-C-specific question. Please tag appropriately.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c) is your answer.

Comment: @jnix i didn't refer to difference between include and import maybe, i didn't make my question clear..

Comment: Entirely different.  All that import/include does is copy lines of code into a compilation unit.  It could be a haiku for all that import/include cares.  But the appropriate definitions must be copied into a compilation unit before they can be referenced for, eg, an inherited class.  (You could physically copy/paste the same lines into your .m and it would be the same.  Unmaintainable, of course, but the compiler wouldn't know the difference.)

Comment: @chrylis i thought in general, i was wondering what is the difference between import and inheritance as both you can technically have pointer to that class...? sorry if i'm going somewhere wrong..

Comment: I do not like writing that but you should really read a good book about object oriented programming. One that covers design pattern (such as mvc, delegation) wold be great.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer to your question is [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) (`:`) is a universal object oriented programming principle and inclusion (`#import`) provides declarations of all symbols used while compiling, which is specific to C like programming languages.

In Objective-C, there is no global symbol space like there is in Java. Each file must include the definition for every symbol used.

This is done by using header files and having interfaces separated from implementations.

The Objective-C compiler only builds .m files, never .h files. The `#import` statement copies the contents of the .h file into the .m file at build time.

MyFoo.h

```
@interface MyFoo : NSObject
@end
```

MyBar.h

```
#import "MyFoo.h"

@interface MyBar : MyFoo
@end
```

MyBar.m

```
#import "MyBar.h"

@implementation MyBar
@end
```

At compile time only MyBar.m is compiled. To the compiler the `#import`s have their source dumped into MyBar.m.

How the compiler see MyBar.m

```
@interface MyFoo : NSObject
@end

@interface MyBar : MyFoo
@end

@implementation MyBar
@end
```

As you can see, the complier cares about the implementation of MyBar and uses the interfaces as a way to provide context for all the declared symbols.

Answer (score 0):

> Importing header file is just referring code written in other file.

while inheritance very different and very powerful concept of Object oriented programming.For good understanding about this please read [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:-

There are no difference between these two, the only thing is #import is modified style which is being used in Objective-c. But #include is the old C style for importing the class.

Answer (score 0):

maybe explaining this in a different way will help you understand..

basically, `#import` doesnt actually do much, its just putting a header inside your .m file.

inheritance is something completely different, this is when an object takes on the properties and functions of another object, and adds some extra functionality to it. eg, a eagle would inherit from an object, bird, since an eagle is a bird but the eagle kind of defines more than just a bird, aka has sharp talons etc.

now for you to be able to do inheritance, you will have to `#import` the header of the base type, eg so in your eagle class, you would need to `#import "bird.h"` to allow you to inherit from it, otherwise the eagle class wont know what a bird is.

the code to do the inheritance would be

```
//Eagle.h

#import "Bird.h"

@interface Eagle : Bird
//insert properties and functions here that would make an eagle an eagle and not just a bird
@end
```

hope that helps a bit with explaining the difference