# What is meaning of #import? if we use #include what happens?

Tags: objective-c, import, include

Why use #import in objective c? if we use #include what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The #import directive was added to Objective-C as an improved version of #include. Whether or not it's improved, however, is still a matter of debate. #import ensures that a file is only ever included once so that you never have a problem with recursive includes. However, most decent header files protect themselves against this anyway, so it's not really that much of a benefit.

Source: [@Jason Coco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439662/what-is-the-difference-between-import-and-include-in-objective-c)

Comment: Keep in mind that #import and #include frequently won't include the whole file and when the rest of the file is required, #import won't be called again.